# MySQL - condition raised in AFTER INSERT trigger and diagnostic area

Tags: mysql

If AFTER INSERT trigger has the following body:

```
BEGIN
...
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000';   #or any other statement that raises warning condition
END;
```

the diagnostic area after successful INSERT statement is cleared and it doesn't contain the warning from last statement within the trigger body.

WHY ?

Is there some internal MySQL statement after the AFTER INSERT trigger which causes the cleanup of diagnostic area ?

Comment: can you show the trigger block?